# Сумма и разница выбранных option в select'

Tags: javascript, jquery

Написал скрипт, который при выборе пунктов select'a подсчитывает сумму чисел, указанных в value у каждого пункта. - https://codepen.io/sergo/pen/pXxEGZ.
Но нужно чтобы работало так же и в обратную сторону, т.е. - убираешь выбранный пункт - он должен исчезнуть и сумма должна уменьшиться на число, указанное в этом пункте. Вот здесь не могу разобраться. Один раз убираешь пункт, сумма уменьшается, а вот следующие уже некорректно работают.
Может кто подскажет. Спасибо большое!

```js
var sum = 0;
var delivery = $('#jqcart-delivery');
var rez = $('#rez');
var elem = $('option');
$(document).on('change', '#myselect', function() {
 var selectedText = $(this).find(':selected').text();
  var selectedVal = $(this).find(':selected').val();
 delivery.append('<p class = "item">' + selectedText + '(' + selectedVal + ')' + '<br>' + '</p>');
 sum += Number(selectedVal);
 $("#rez").html(sum);
 
 $('.item').on('click', function(){
  $(this).remove();
  sum -= Number(selectedVal);
  $("#rez").html(sum);
 });
 
});
```

```css
.item{ 
 position: relative;
}
.item:after{
 content: "x";
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="user_delivery" id="myselect">
<option value="0">Самовывоз</option>
<option value="100">Доставка до ТК</option>
<option value="200">Доставка по РФ</option>
<option value="300">Доставка курьером</option>
<option value="400">Доставка почтой</option>
</select>
<div id="jqcart-delivery">Доставка: <br> </div>
<div id="rez"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас не будет работать потому что вы берете первый елемент из select. В select только один элемент может иметь значение selected. Присваивай option класс active а потом перебирай c помощью each.

```js
var sum = 0;
var delivery = $('#jqcart-delivery');
var rez = $('#rez');
var elem = $('option');
$(document).on('change', '#myselect', function() {
 var selectedText = $(this).find(':selected').text();
  var selectedVal = $(this).find(':selected').val();
 delivery.append('<p class="item">' + selectedText + '(<span>' + selectedVal + '</span>)' + '<br>' + '</p>');
 sum += Number(selectedVal);
 $("#rez").html(sum);
});

$(document).on('click','.item', function(){
  $(this).remove();
  var prev = $(this).children('span').text();
  sum = $('#rez').text() - Number(prev);
  $("#rez").html(sum);
 });
```

```css
.item{ 
 position: relative;
}
.item:after{
 content: "x";
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="user_delivery" id="myselect">
<option value="0">Самовывоз</option>
<option value="100">Доставка до ТК</option>
<option value="200">Доставка по РФ</option>
<option value="300">Доставка курьером</option>
<option value="400">Доставка почтой</option>
</select>
<div id="jqcart-delivery">Доставка: <br> </div>
<div id="rez"></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Очень помогли!